# get geotag info for photos using PHImageManager

Tags: ios, photos, info

I'm trying to list geo tag info (longitude and latitude) for all photos, obtained using

```
PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(fetchResult.objectAtIndex(1) as! PHAsset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0), contentMode: PHImageContentMode.AspectFill, options: options) { (image, info)
```

however, info doesn't seem to contain this information,
is there any way to get this information using Photos framework?

thank you,
Anton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHAsset itself hold the CLLocation (i.e geo location) for the image. 
There is no need to request image data for it.

All you need to do is

```
fetchResult.objectAtIndex(1).location
```

Here is the link to the documentation page for PHAsset https://developer.apple.com/reference/photos/phasset